# Behance API var starts with number

Tags: php, api

at Behance API a get an array of objects that are my projects. But when I print cover object i get this:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [115] => https://m1.behance.net/profiles18/2701167/projects/8725001/115x461b2d628417adeead62b8ee18869cea.jpg
    [202] => https://m1.behance.net/profiles18/2701167/projects/8725001/461b2d628417adeead62b8ee18869cea.jpg
    [404] => https://m1.behance.net/profiles18/2701167/projects/8725001/404x461b2d628417adeead62b8ee18869cea.jpg
    [230] => https://m1.behance.net/profiles18/2701167/projects/8725001/230x461b2d628417adeead62b8ee18869cea.jpg
)
```

So, how access variables that start with numbers in PHP ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If that was stored in a variable named `$object` and you wanted to get to the value of key `202`:

```
$object->{'202'}
```

Comment: I love you! Thanks :) I thought it was: $object->['202'] like JS